# Ionic v2 app iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having trouble with my app when I build it using `ionic emulate ios`. My loading page is always running (so the index.html) without charging my app. Yet it perfectly works with Chrome Developper Tools.

Does someone know why ?

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your problem, somewhere in the `app.ts` file you've enabled on launch a `loading` function but without any explicit `duration` or was set too long.

If you are using any `Cordova Plugins`, some bugs won't appear on the Chrome Developer since native functions are not tested so when you use an emulator native bugs become apparent. Try disabling or removing select cordova plugins to determine the root cause.

Comment: I didn't use a loading function so I guess it's a cordova plugin error.